# Heroku/Rails/Devise/Refinery CMS: IE requires that I have "Accept All Cookies" setting to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, heroku, devise, refinerycms

I'm running a Refinery CMS application that uses Devise as the plugin for logging in/authentication. The problem I am having is that Chrome/FF are working fine but IE is not logging the user in. At first, I believed it was that the SSL Certificate wasn't set up yet. After I fixed the SSL issue with Heroku, the problem remained.

Changing the privacy setting for cookies to "Accept all Cookies" is the only workaround I've found to fix this problem. This is problematic because I have to explain to my clients why their IE browser isn't working and at the same time they have to expose themselves to 3rd party cookies if they use this browser for other internet applications.

Is there a configuration that I can set in Rails 3/Refinery/Devise that will remedy this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem - fixed it by using a different session_store in config/initializers/session_store.rb

The :cookie_store default session store tries to store all session information on the browser (which is why you had to set the "Accept all Cookies" in IE). As an example I set my session store to :active_record_store and it solved the login issues.

Coincidentally, I had this problem with IE8, but IE9 and IE10 didn't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: ok thanks man. I'll accept and upvote when I've verified this.